# PHP remove duplicate records from multidimensional array based on key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my original array example:

```
Array ( [product_id] => 5 [receipt] => R5B1A2L8 )
Array ( [product_id] => 5 [receipt] => R5V3ABWR )
Array ( [product_id] => 7 [receipt] => R2B3AC2M )
```

I want to be remove duplicate records from the array based on 'product_id' key. The array is generated from a database so the array values can change.

Here is the result I want to achieve:

```
Array ( [product_id] => 5 [receipt] => R5B1A2L8 )
Array ( [product_id] => 7 [receipt] => R2B3AC2M )
```

Comment: You better solve this off with a SQL query. Show your table rows and your query.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you tried already, or at least something you managed to research – and not _just_ give us the “specification” of your problem.

Comment: Why you want to save `[receipt] => R5B1A2L8` and to lose `[receipt] => R5V3ABWR`. Maybe it will be enough to get unique ids ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do a

```
$unique = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($unique[$value['product_id']]) {
        unset ($arr[$key]);
    } else {
        $unique[$value['product_id']] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's just a static way of doing this

Comment: The key should be based 'product_id' not 'receipt'. Also the array will be dynamically generated from a database so I won't know the exact values.

Comment: @MMaavia Yes, you are right, I have fixed the code. I misunderstood what was expected.

Comment: @ianhman Yes, you are right. I misunderstood the question. I have fixed the code

Answer (score 0):

```
function multi_unique($src){
    $output = array_map("unserialize",
    array_unique(array_map("serialize", $src)));
    return $output;
   }

 //Call function

   $reqArray=array( array("name","name"), 
        array("age","12"), 
        array("name","parvez"), 
        array("add","delhi")
 );

  $output=multi_unique($reqArray);
```

please see above example
or this one may help you

```
   $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = array(array('product_id'=>5,'receipt'=>'sdsd'),array('product_id'=>5,'receipt'=>'dswe'),array('product_id'=>6,'receipt'=>'arewr'));
        $tempArr = array_unique(array_column($input, 'product_id'));
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r(array_intersect_key($input, $tempArr));
        exit;
```

Do with your array.

```
$tempArr = array_unique(array_column($array, 'product_id'));
print_r(array_intersect_key($array, $tempArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the input array and push the found keys to a secondary array if the key isn't found, otherwise unset the item

```
// $array is your input array

$product_ids = []; // Create a second temp array

foreach($array as $key => $item): // Loop your input array
    if ( in_array($item['product_id'],$product_ids) ){ // Check if the current item exists in our temp array
        unset ($array[$key]); // If it does, remove the current item from our input array
    } else {
        $product_ids[] = $item['product_id']; // Otherwise push the key to our temp array
    }
endforeach;

print_r($array);
```

This will retain the original array indexes. If you want incremental indexes you can push the items to a new array instead of unsetting from the original array

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

$products = [
    [
        'product_id' => 5,
        'receipt' => 'R5B1A2L8',
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => 5,
        'receipt' => 'R5V3ABWR',
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => 7,
        'receipt' => 'R2B3AC2M',
    ],
];

// gives you unique product_id indexes, here 0 and 2
$uniqueKeys = array_unique(array_column($products, 'product_id'));
// extract previous indexes from your products array
$uniqueProducts = array_intersect_key($products, $uniqueKeys);

var_dump($uniqueProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function array_unset($arr,$key){     
    $res = array();        
    foreach ($arr as $value) {            
       if(isset($res[$value[$key]])){   
             unset($value[$key]);  
       }  
       else{  
            $res[$value[$key]] = $value;  
       }    
    }  
    return $res;  
}  
$arr = array(   
        array('product_id'=>'5','receipt'=>'R5B1A2L8' ),  
        array('product_id'=>'5','receipt'=>'R5V3ABWR'),  
        array('product_id'=>'7','receipt'=>'R2B3AC2M')  
);  
$newArr = array_unset($arr,'product_id');  
echo '<pre>';  
print_r(array_values($newArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this function for removing duplicated records:

```
array_unique($my_array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: This doesn't work as only [product_id] column has a duplicate, [receipt] column values are unique.